# python reads only few rows of a table of pdf

Tags: python

I have a table in ppt format and I convert it to pdf so that I can use tabula to read and extract the table. Then save table as a csv file.

After all, I only see a few rows of the table extracted from pdf in csv file.

can anybody please guide me how can I figure this out? Thanks.

```
import tabula

from tabula import read_pdf

import pandas as pd

from tabula import read_pdf


tabula.convert_into(r"C:\Users\zjalil\Desktop\CDS_Analytical2.pdf", "CLD.csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Why do you convert the PPT file into PDF? For a single file, you can do this with PowerPoint and/or Excel. No code needed.

Comment: @AyushGupta added the code: (which works perfect for a pdf with table that I had but not the pdf that I got from ppt)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : the ppt does slide does not only contain a table so, I figures with a line of code I can get the table, do you have any suggestions? thanks

Comment: I would copy the data from the PPT table and then paste it into Excel. Then you can save it as CSV. Unless you need to automate this for 100s of files, there is no need to write code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes I will need to do this for few slides and would be great to automate it, any suggestions?

Comment: Use a pptx library, like [python-pptx](https://pypi.org/project/python-pptx/)